# How to change image caption in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, caption

In Microsoft Word, I want to change the caption of an image from the default **Figure 3** to **3 Figure**.

[image]

It is possible? I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you show more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. This would need to be added manually every time, it does *not* create a new label format.

   1. Go to `References` `->` `Insert Caption`.
   2. In the dialog box, check the option `Exclude label from caption`.
   3. Type your post-label (`Figure`) after the auto number
2. [This](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/numbers-before-labels-in-captions/50b9c9ad-efb2-4de4-81f1-f0e1e1dc62db) solution provides a degree of automation. You should of course substitute `Figure` instead of `Equation`.

   > You could use SEQ fields to number them (though not automatically).
   >
   > 1. Create a SEQ field e.g `{ SEQ Equation \# "# equation" }`
   >      (the brackets are placed with CTRL+F9)
   > 2. save it as an autocorrect entry for (say) #eq
   > 3. insert it wherever you wish, or simply copy and paste.
   >
   > **Note:** SEQ fields do not update automatically so you can either select the document (CTRL+A) and update (F9) or use a macro to do so - see the example at http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already added an image to a word file and you already added an image caption via the "Insert Caption" menu item, you can edit the caption text directly OR you can just insert another caption label. At the Caption menu click on "New Label..." button. This will change the label of the caption you want.
You need to re-add the new caption with the updated label though.

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

try adding a default caption, say Figure 3, from the "Insert Caption" window, and after you click "OK" you will have the caption text box where you can edit it to whatever you want.
Hope this helps!